# Hyperlink in PHP file

Tags: php, hyperlink

The link in a HTML file:

```
<a href="<?= Config::get('URL') . 'profile/showProfile/' . $user->user_id; ?>">Profile</a>
```

Works!
The same link in a PHP file:

```
echo "<a href='"<?= Config::get('URL') . 'profile/showProfile/' . $user->user_id; ?>"'>Profile</a>";
```

Does not work!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you have short-tags enabled?

replace `<?=` to `<?php echo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to include `<?=` when you are already executing as PHP code.

```
echo "<a href='" . Config::get('URL') . 'profile/showProfile/' . $user->user_id . "'>Profile</a>";
```

Comment: No problem mate. Sometimes it is the simplest things that we overlook. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$url = Config::get('URL');
echo "<a href='".$url. 'profile/showProfile/'.$user->user_id."'>Profile</a>";
```